# Change span color on div hover

Tags: html, css, image, hover

Sorry if this is stupid question but i really don't know what problem is.I am trying to change color of span on div's hover but my code doesn't seems to work.
Here is code i'am using:

**HTML**

```
<div class="slike_i_text">


    <a href="#"><div>
    <img align="left" src="wolf.jpg"/><span>Text 1</span></div></a>

    <a href="#"><div>
    <img align="left" src="wolf.jpg"/><span>Text 2</span></div></a>



</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.slike_i_text div{
    overflow: hidden;
    width:300px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.slike_i_text div img{
    width:80px;
    height:80px;
}
.slike_i_text div span{
    color: #6A6A6A;
font-family: arial;
font-size: 15px;
font-weight: bold;
}
.slike_i_text a{
    text-decoration: none;
}
.slike_i_text div:hover  .slike_i_text div span{
    color:lightgreen;

}
```

You can find my fiddle **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/Ur6fq/)**.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may try this ([Updated Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Ur6fq/1/)):

```
.slike_i_text div:hover span{
    color:lightgreen;
}
```

Instead of this:

```
.slike_i_text div:hover  .slike_i_text div span{
    color:lightgreen;
}
```

Comment: Man thank u, this is what i want.Thanks once again :D

Comment: May i know for Inline

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to go like `.slike_i_text div:hover  .slike_i_text div span` instead you should use `.slike_i_text div:hover span`.

fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Ur6fq/4/)

Comment: may i know for inline

Comment: will you give me some context?